# SARIMA with daily data - determine saisonal period

Tags: python, arima

i have 30 years for daily temperature data and  i have a problem with determinate the saisonal period  , i cant do it with lag = 365 day  python is implemented

so can i use 90 day ( 1 season) . I don't know does it make sense or not

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use a yearly lag when you have thirty years of data?

Comment: I tried with a lag of 365 days but python stops before finishing the fit and sent me this message: 'the kernel seems to be installed it will restart automatically'

Answer (score 1):

A seasonality of 365 does not really make sense for three reasons:

1. Such a long seasonality often leads to long runtimes or as in your case the process breaks.
2. When you use exactly 365 days you are ignoring leap years, so you model distorts over longer periods (30 years for examples results a distortion of 7 days already)
3. The most important reason is the correlation itself. A seasonality of 365 would mean that the weather today is somehow correlated to the weather last year, which is not really the case. Of course, both days will be somewhat close to another due to meteorological seasons, but I would not rely on this correlation. Imagine last year was relatively cold and this year is relatively warm. Do you use the last days immediately before today or would you base your forecast on some day a year ago? That is not very reliable.

Your forecast has to be based on the last immediate lags before the actual day – not the days of last year. However, to improve your model you have to factor in the meteorological seasons (spring, summer, fall, winter). There are multiple ways to do so. One for example would be to use SARIMAX and pass the model an exogenous feature, e.g. the monthly average temperature or a moving average over the last years. That way you can teach the model that days in summer are generally hotter than in winter, and for the precise prediction you use the days immediately before.
See here for the documentation of statsmodels SARIMAX:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html

There are plenty of examples on how to create these models with exogenous variables on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I want to model a time series of energy imports that is seasonal because energy consumption depends on the weather but there are also other drivers e.g. economic growth, energy prices, infrastructure development. The data is daily. There is 10 years of history. I'd like to model with daily granularity (or weekly otherwise) to capture intramonth changes e.g. temperature/price dislocations and ‘moving’ holidays. Is there a way to achieve this with SARIMA and if so, how can I circumvent the issues you raised? Most SARIMA examples I've seen use monthly data.